# preg with any char and limit {x,y}

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, expression, preg-match-all

I have a problem the day and can not solve...
I need to create a regular expression to take any char within a limit of X and Y.

```
preg_match( '#\((.*)\)#' ,'11(22)33' , $match );
```

the above rule is the occurrence 22
but what I need is to increase a limit {2,4} and when the rule do not work

```
preg_match( '#\((.*)\){5,10}#' , '11(22)33' , $match );
```

I need to serve any kind of character - digit, word, symbol...

Comment: can you show us some before and after match strings

Comment: the example I posted above is what I'm using as a test

Comment: @PapaCharlie it seems that you need to [learn regex](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/) ...

Comment: believe, already read a lot and could not create this rule

Comment: @PapaCharlie Could you join [the regex chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/) to clarify further the issue ?

Comment: very grateful, but my English is pessimo to chat, but I'll try in a bit - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is a short version of `{0,}`, i.e. minimum 0 chars, no upper limit. You can replace the asterisk with your version of the limit: `{5,10}`. Any five to ten characters would be `.{5,10}`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand... rule changes to **#\\((.*)\\){5,10}#**

Comment: I followed what you said and got this rule: **#^(.{5,10})$#**. I do not have enough knowledge, I wonder if this correct? Thank you

Comment: Does it grab you between 5 and 10 characters? What is your input and expected output? Would be great if you can edit your question with more info.

Comment: yes, I'm using **#^(.{5.10})$#** i'm getting the contents between 5,10 to true or false when outside rule. I'm using as part of a verification and validation of data. thanks